# Lasso regression in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, linear-regression

I am using `lasso` function in matlab 2013a. It works as follows:

```
    X = randn(100,5);
    r = [0;2;0;-3;0];
    Y = X*r + randn(100,1)*.1; 
%Construct the lasso fit using ten-fold cross validation. Include the FitInfo 
%output so you can plot the result.
    [B FitInfo] = lasso(X,Y,'CV',10); %B is a p-by-L matrix, where p is the %number of predictors (columns) in X, and L is the number of Lambda values

%Plot the cross-validated fits.
    lassoPlot(B,FitInfo,'PlotType','CV');
```

[image]

The green circle and dashed line locate the Lambda with minimal cross-validation error. The blue circle and dashed line locate the point with minimal cross-validation error plus one standard deviation.

So what I understand is that the green circle corresponds to the best value of lambda which minimizes the error. **But how I can find "automatically" (without need of drawing the figure) the vector B which corresponds to the value of lambda shown as green circle in the figure?.**

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/lasso.html) it should be in `FitInfo.Lambda`, which is a `1xL` vector containing the lambdas. You can probably find it using `min(FitInfo.Lambda)`.
If you set the `CV` name-value pair to `cross validate`, the `FitInfo` structure contains additional fields: `FitInfo.LambdaMinMSE` which is the exact value you're looking for.

Thanks to @Christina, this is a slightly compacter way of writing it:

```
bestValue = find(FitInfo.Lambda == FitInfo.LambdaMinMSE)
```

This will give you the index where the minimum lambda is located in the array `L`